# Two racket modules colliding

Tags: module, scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I am requiring two modules to my file:

```
(require sicp) ; contains set-car! and set-cdr!
(require (planet dyoo/sicp-concurrency:1:2/sicp-concurrency)) ; contains procedures parallel-execute and test-and-set!
```

Problem: both libraries use different flavors of scheme. The sicp-concurrency uses mzscheme. Requiring this module prevented me from using else in a cond clause.

Is there a way to prevent the features of mzscheme in sicp-concurrency while still making use of the procedures I needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated Danny Yoo's code to Racket 7.
Get the new file "sicp-concurrency.rkt" here:

https://gist.github.com/soegaard/d32e12d89705c774b71ee78ef930a4bf

Save the file in the same folder as your program file.
Here is an example of use:

```
#lang sicp
(#%require "sicp-concurrency.rkt")

(define (test-1)
  (define x 10)
  (parallel-execute (lambda () (set! x (* x x)))
                    (lambda () (set! x (+ x 1))))
  x)

(define (test-2)
  (define x 10)
  (define s (make-serializer))
  (parallel-execute (s (lambda () (set! x (* x x))))
                    (s (lambda () (set! x (+ x 1)))))
  x)

(test-1)
(test-1)
(test-1)
(test-1)
(test-1)
```